# Problems loading an obfuscated jar in DBVisualizer

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, dbvisualizer

I have a jar which I need to prevent others from decompiling. So I obfuscated it using ProGuard. But after obfuscation, I'm not able to load the jar file in DbVisualizer, because it throws ClassDefNotFound exception. The original class names are renamed to some random characters like 'a' and 'b'. I tried -keep option with some classes, however I ended up excluding many classes in the process.
Is there an alternate way to load an obfuscated Jar file in DBVisualiser?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: do you need to load it after obsfucation? It would save you a lot of headaches

Comment: Yes. As we need to deliver only an obfuscated jar to the customer, they should be able to load the obfuscated jar using the java application. But currently when I try to load the obfuscated jar it throws ClassDefNotFound exception as the class are renamed.

Comment: That is the catch. Try the pg UI and weed out only the classes you need to make it load. I think pg has a way to dump the obsfucation map, and read stack traces but none of these will help you, I think